# Attention mechanism with different layer size?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, attention-model, encoder-decoder

i have two layer with different layer sizes (hidden states) how can i perform encoder decoder type of attention on these layers if the layer sizes are different? because i will do dot product, how?

Consider I have two layers:

```
lstm1 = LSTM(20, return_sequences=True, name='lstm')

lstm2 = LSTM(40, return_sequences=True, name='lstm')
```

How is possible to apply attention here since dot product would be not possible?

Thanks

I created my own Attention class and it worked with same LSTM hidden state sizes

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/alvations/kopitiam/blob/master/Kopitiam%20mit%20Attention.ipynb Hope it helps!